# Does the smooth manifold $\#_{l}CP^{2}\#_{k}(-CP^{2})$ admit a symplectic structure?

Tags: symplectic-topology

Let $-CP^{2}$ denote the complex projective surface  $CP^{2}$ with the reverse orientation. I have seen some results about the existence of symplectic structures on the connected sums $\#_{l}CP^{2}\#_{k}(-CP^{2})$ for **some** positive integers l,k.

My question is whether there is a complete result which can decribe the existence of symplectic structures on the connected sums $\#_{l}CP^{2}\#_{k}(-CP^{2})$ for **all** positive integers l,k.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $l=1$, these are blowups of the projective plane, which are all Kaehler and hence symplectic.  For $l>1$, these do not have symplectic structures.  For if $l$ is even, then they don't even have almost complex structures [(cf. this MO thread)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59820/a-question-on-classification-of-almost-complex-structures-on-4-manifolds), which symplectic manifolds certainly do. If $l>1$ is odd, then their Seiberg-Witten invariants would vanish, since your manifolds decompose as a connected sum into pieces with positive $b_2^+$. But a famous theorem of Taubes says that there is a non-vanishing Seiberg-Witten invariant.

Finally, if $l=0$, then $b_2^+ = 0$, so your manifold cannot be symplectic, since the cohomology class of the symplectic form has positive square.

Comment: "The cohomology class of the symplectic form has positive square" : I wonder what is your definition of a symplectic strucuture. For me, a symplectic form remains symplectic if one changes the orientation. In particular, the answer should be positive for $k=1$ and all $l$.

Comment: @abx But a symplectic form canonically defines an orientation of the underlying manifold. If you had already chosen a preferred orientation of your manifold, it makes sense to look for symplectic forms inducing the same orientation. There are no symplectic forms on $CP^{2}$ which would induce an orientation different from the standard one.

Comment: I agree, but then the question should be slightly modified (… a symplectic structure *compatible with the orientation*).

Comment: @abx But that is clear-ish from how the question is asked, isn't it? Otherwise we would not talk about "$-CP^{2}$."

Comment: I agree with the comment of abx and indeed meant to include a similar remark as a preface to my answer, but was in a bit of a hurry.  I took the question to be about symplectic structures compatible with a given orientation.

Comment: Thank a lot for a clear answer! Moreover, I'd like to know how about considering all the smooth manifolds **homeomorphic** to $\#_{l}CP^{2}\#_{k}(-CP^{2})$ for $l$ is odd.

Comment: That's a much more complicated answer; there are some that have symplectic structures, some that don't.  By the argument I outlined above, you should assume that your manifold is irreducible, ie not a connected sum of manifolds with $b_2^+ >0$. There is a very large literature on the subject, starting with [Szabó, Zoltán, Simply-connected irreducible 4-manifolds with no symplectic structures. Invent. Math. 132 (1998), no. 3, 457–466.] I would also look at [R. Fintushel and R. Stern, Knots, links, and 4-manifolds, Invent. Math. 134 (1998), 363–400.]

Comment: I also want to know why $S^{2n}$ can not be regarded as a symplectic blow down of $\overline{CP^{n}}$.