# Are there known examples of almost complex manifolds admitting neither a symplectic nor a complex structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I have seen the the example of $S^6$ being touted around here and there but it does not seem to be generally confirmed that there is no complex structure on it.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2$ (I recommend asking on math.stackexchange.com for details)

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^2\sharp\mathbb{CP}^2\sharp\mathbb{CP}^2$

Comment: do you happen to have a source for further reading?

Comment: For example http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-58736 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/151638

Comment: @YangMills that mathoverflow link does not answer this in the affirmative, it says there is no symplectic structure compatible with the given orientation, not that there is no symplectic structure

Comment: Of course, the orientation was fixed implicitly in the notation (otherwise you would write $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}\sharp\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}\sharp \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$). Anyway, the statement that the opposite orientation doesn't have any compatible symplectic structure either follows from Prop. 13.3.13 in McDuff-Salamon (Introduction... 3rd ed.), see also Ex. 13.3.14.

Comment: In his Fields Medal address, Atiyah asked the question, "Can one avoid the machinery of topology' in the proof of the index theorem. Grothendieck in the audience answered, 'The topology must be at least that of the complex numbers since there is a Galois action on the set of possible definitions'.